# In what does this simple do notation desugar to?

Tags: haskell, do-notation

I'm using `Aeson` and `Network.HTTP`. I was able to encode a json and print it on the screen doing the following:

```
getCode :: String -> IO ResponseCode
getCode url = simpleHTTP req >>= getResponseCode
    where req = getRequest url

main :: IO ()
main = do 
    x <- get "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
    let y = encode x
    B.putStrLn y
```

However I do not understand what this `do` expression desugars to. Something like this:

```
get "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1" >>= (?)
```

what should be in the `?`?

I only know how to desugar this:

```
do { x1 <- action1
   ; x2 <- action2
   ; mk_action3 x1 x2 }
```

to this

```
action1 >>= (\ x1 -> action2 >>= (\ x2 -> mk_action3 x1 x2 ))
```

bu the way, what is an `action`? https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation does not explain very precisely.

Comment: one question at a time please, and thank you.

Comment: `B.putStrLn (encode x)` is an IO action, just like `action1` or `mk_action3 x1 x2`.

Comment: If you want the precise rules, go to https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14

Comment: Action is an informal term to refer to something with a type wrapped in a Monad, for example `getLine :: IO String` is an action that gets a line of input, or `put :: s -> State s ()` is an action that modifies State. IO and State are both Monads so we can call these actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1" >>= (\x -> let y = encode x in B.putStrLn y)`

Answer (score 0):

`put (x :: s)` is a `State s` "action".

`put :: s -> State s ()` is a function from `s` type values to `State s` "actions", an "action" constructor.

`putStrLn "Hi"` is an `IO` action. `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()` is a function from `String`s to `IO` actions, an "action" constructor.

`IO` is a Monad. `State s` is a Monad.

an "action" is any value of type `M a` where `M` is a Monad.